# Why BOOT MENU doesn't read USB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, debian

I've a LENOVO G50. I'd ubuntu but I would install debian from USB. So, I'd run usb with debian iso etc. but didn't run. So, I'd try with Elementary but I don't liked it. So, I tried Kali Linux in USB and now I have a big problem, If I join in BOOT MENU I can watch only: ubuntu (if I click it I watch just a grub) and EFI 0 for Network IPV4 and IPV6. I have insert USB in the pc but I can't select/look it in boot menu. Why?

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, you did the same procedure as you did with Debian and Elementary, but with Kali it didn't work?

In that case, I'd imagine it's because of the way you've copied the ISO to your USB drive, you might have to do it differently for Kali. I'd try gnome-disks if I were you, it's always worked for me.

Comment: No, I tried with every usb (also that with elementary/debian) and now boot doesn't ready nothing USB bootable

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I'd try another USB drive.

Comment: @Blind use this: http://pendrivelinux.com/